# Resolving wins 7 domain join issue

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-7

Please, I have tried everything possible to resolve the issue of joining my wins7 client computers to the domain. I have been getting dns resolution error whenever an attempt is made to join the domain.
I do not have any issue joining the wins xp client to the domain. 
My topology: An AD & DC server (Used as file server only), an off site dns (ISP) a forwarder was configured, I have a loop-back as primary dns on the server and the ISP DNS as the alt. 
The workstations get IP via DHCP. Part of the error message I do get is that I should verify if te computer is configured to join the domain.
Kindly assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The DC shouldn't have a non-AD DNS server in its list. Fix that first.

Then verify that your Windows 7 clients  are using **only** domain controllers for your domain for DNS. This smells like a pretty cut-and-dry DNS configuration issue.

Comment: MDMarra, maybe this is not the time and place to ask, but will DCs (if they act as nameservers for the domain) be able to resolve domain names? Will they send recursive queries to root-servers? Thanks!

Comment: They will if they're configured to do so - which they are by default.

Comment: I've done what you suggested but still getting this error message: "An attempt to resolve the DNS name of a domain controller in the domain being joined has failed. Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server that can reslove DNS names in the target domain."